# Copiar (cp) para a pasta atual no LINUX

Tags: linux, bash, console

É possível eximir caminho de destino ao dar um comando para copiar (cp) no console do linux para a pasta atual/corrente?

**Ex:**

```
cp ~/Origem ~/Destino
```

O que eu desejo é algum atalho no bash equivalente ao destino.

**Ex:**

```
cp ~/Origem <atalho equivalente à ~/Destino (diretório atual/corrente) >
```

Comment: Se tiver entendido corretamente, links simbólicos são a solução (utilize o comando `ln -s` para criá-los - veja a manpage para mais detalhes).

Comment: Onde eu leio sobre o que, e o que não pergunta no Stackoverflow? Aqui 'aculá' tenho levado umas lenhadas ou pergunta com votos pra fechá-la.

Comment: Fiquei curioso também o por que de a pergunta ser suspensa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> É possível eximir caminho de destino ao dar um comando para copiar
>   (cp) no console do linux para a pasta atual/corrente?

Sim, é possível e é até bastante simples.

A directoria actual pode ser representada por `.`

Sabendo isto, o comando

```
cp ~/Origem .
```

irá copiar para a directoria actual (`echo $PWD`) o ficheiro `Origem` que se encontra na tua directoria pessoal.

Da mesma forma, podes usar `..` para, por exemplo, copiar um ficheiro para a directoria que se encontra no nível imediatamente superior ao da directoria actual.

Por exemplo, imagina que estás na directoria `~/nivel1/nivel2`, ao executar o comando

```
cp ~/Origem ../
```

Irás copiar o ficheiro `Origem` para a directoria `~/nivel1`

Answer (score 2):

Opa. Acredito que você esteja querendo criar links simbólicos.

TIPO SIMBÓLICO

No link tipo simbólico, o link é um arquivo especial de disco do tipo link, que tem como conteúdo o caminho para chegar até o arquivo alvo.

Características:
Pode-se fazer links simbólicos em arquivos e diretórios;
O link simbólico e o arquivo alvo não precisam estar na mesma partição de disco;
Se o link simbólico for apagado/movido. Somente o link será apagado/movido;
Qualquer usuário pode criar/desfazer um link simbólico (respeitando as permissões).

**TIPO HARDLINK**

No link tipo hardlink, o link é apontado para o mesmo inode do arquivo alvo, sendo assim, os dois arquivos serão o mesmo.

Características:
Não é possível fazer um hardlink para um diretório;
Somente é possível fazer hardlink em arquivos que estejam em uma mesma partição de disco;
Se o hardlink for apagado/movido, você estará apagando/movendo o arquivo alvo;
Somente o usuário root pode criar/desfazer hardlinks.

**CRIANDO LINKS**

O comando ln é utilizado para criar links entre dois arquivos ou para um diretório.

Sintaxe:

```
ln [OPÇÕES]... [-T] ALVO NOME_LINK   (1a forma)
ln [OPÇÕES]... ALVO                  (2a forma)
ln [OPÇÕES]... ALVO... DIRETÓRIO     (3a forma)
ln [OPÇÕES]... -t DIRETÓRIO ALVO...  (4a forma)
```

Explicando:

ALVO: Diretório ou arquivo de onde será feito o link;
NOME_LINK: Nome do link que será criado;
OPÇÕES:

-s
    Cria um link simbólico. 
-v
    Modo verbose.

Exemplos:

1 - Criando um link simbólico chamado "emulador" para o diretório /home/roberto/download/emulador_n64/:

`$ ln -s /home/roberto/download/emulador_n64/ emulador`

Note que o link simbólico é identificado com o "l" no início.

`$ ls -lah | grep emulador lrwxrwx--x  1 roberto    roberto      36 2006-10-12 22:42 emulador -> /home/roberto/download/emulador_n64/`

2 - Criando um hardlink chamado "texto.txt" apontando para o arquivo "alvo_hardlink.txt":

`$ ln alvo_hardlink.txt texto.txt`

Note que o arquivo "alvo_hardlink.txt" e o arquivo texto.txt possuem o mesmo Inode e o mesmo Device.

`$ stat alvo_hardlink.txt | grep Inode
Device: 304h/772d       Inode: 3057948     Links: 2`

`$ stat texto.txt | grep Inode
Device: 304h/772d       Inode: 3057948     Links: 2`

Fonte: http://www.vivaolinux.com.br/dica/Link-simbolico-e-hardlink